# Question about strcpy using char pointer in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, sizeof, strcpy

I'm doing some programming with C, and I have a minor problem using strcpy.

```
char* file="It has something inside"
int size= sizeof(file);
char* file_save = malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
strcpy(file_save,file);
```

My code stopped working in the last line.
What can be the problem here?

It seems like something went wrong outside this part of the code. It works perfectly well if I change sizeof into strlen in the online gdb, but it still stops in the strcpy line on my computer's VS code. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: The size of a pointer (which is what `sizeof(file)` will give you) is the size of the pointer itself, not what it points to. You want to use `strlen(file)` to get the length of the string. And remember to add one when allocating, to account for the string terminator.

Comment: Change `int size= sizeof(file);` to `int size= strlen(file)+1`.  The +1 is for the null char.

Comment: @selbie Why you added `1` to the `strlen` result?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi for the null terminator

Comment: `char* file` -> `char file[]` or you can't use `sizeof`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I changed my code to strlen. Thank you for this part. But there must be other problems besides that. My code still does not work in the strcpy line.

Comment: Then you have some other problem with the code, possibly with code you don't show us. Please try to create a [mre] and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: It seems like something went wrong outside this part of the code. It works perfectly well in the online gdb, but it stops in the strcpy line on my computer's VS code. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You could also use `const char file[] = “…”;` and then `sizeof(file)` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments suggest, the `size` is the size of variable char pointer which is probably 8 if you are working on a 64-bit machine. So you need the size of string the `file` is pointing to. You can get that like below:

```c
int size = strlen(file) + 1;
```

The `strlen` returns the number of bytes this string has. Every string is finished by a null terminator `\0`. While you are writing in a file it doesn't matter which bytes are for the string and which is the null terminator so you need to count both.

Comment: Maybe mention the reason of the +1.

Comment: Yes, I changed my code to strlen. Thank you for this part. 
But there must be other problems besides that. My code still does not work in the strcpy line.

Comment: would you provide more detail? what happen? the program crashes with segmentation fault?
@linki

Comment: @linki You can edit your question and **add** the new version, and don't forget to include the error description.

Comment: It seems like something went wrong outside this part of the code. It works perfectly well in the online gdb, but it stops in the strcpy line on my computer's VS code. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `file` has the pointer type `char *`

```
char* file="It has something inside";
```

It would be even better to declare the pointer with the qualifier `const` because you may not change the string literal pointed to by the pointer

```
const char *file = "It has something inside";
```

Its size returned by the operator `sizeof`

```
int size= sizeof(file);
```

does not depend on what string the pointer points to and usually is equal to 4 or 8 bytes.

As you are going to copy the pointed string literal you need to determine its length. To do this you can use standard string function `strlen`. It returns the number of characters in a string until the terminating zero character `'\0'` is encountered.

So you need to write

```
size_t size = strlen( file );
```

Now you need to allocate memory for `size` characters plus one for the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal.

```
char* file_save = malloc( size + 1 );
```

So all is ready to copy the source string provided that the memory was allocated successfully.

```
strcpy( file_save, file );
```

Answer (score 0):

> What can be the problem here?

A *pointer* is not an *array* and not a *string*.  An array is not a pointer.  A string is not a pointer.

Below, `file` is a *pointer*.

```
char* file = "It has something inside";
int size = sizeof(file);
```

`sizeof(file)` is the size of a *pointer*, not the size of array nor the size of a *string*.

Later code needs to use the size of a *string*, not the size of a pointer.

---

To find the size of a *string*, use the pointer `file`, which points to a *string* and then call `strlen()`.

```
// `length` is the string length: characters up to, but not including the null character.
size_t length = strlen(file);

// `size` is the string size: characters up to, and including the null character.
size_t size = length + 1;
```

Use `size` to determine allocation needs for a copy of the string.